# Wordpress is refusing to load

Tags: php, wordpress, apache

I've been trying to install a wordpress blog on an apache virtualhost for several days now to no avail. Note, the virtual host configuration works just fine, as each virtual host loads up its respective index.html or index.php. Only on a Wordpress install do I get no response. My conf file looks like

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example

    <Directory /var/www/example/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

The blog is located in directory /var/www/example and my .htaccess file looks like

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I have mod_rewrite enabled, so I'm not sure what the issue is. Checking the apache error log turns up nothing and the access logs always show a return of 301. Any ideas?

Comment: So what happens when you try to open wordpress homepage?

Comment: @DusanBajic The homepage never resolves. It times out after a couple of minutes.

Comment: You need to check the basics first. What if you remove .htaccess and create a simple index.html in site root folder, can you open it?

Comment: @DusanBajic The virtual host works just fine. It will load up an index,html or a default index.php file just fine. It's just loading wordpress that causes the host to not resolve.

Comment: try `curl -v http://example.com` and look for `Location:` header in response

Comment: @DusanBajic When I do that I get the HTTP 301 error. Location: http://example.com:8888/. I have no idea why it keeps defaulting to port 8888. It's also behind cloudflare, but I get the same results when I turn cloudflare off or in development mode, so I don't think it's that.

Comment: Check if [Wordpress Site Url](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL) is set correctly

Comment: @DusanBajic Hmm, I added define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com'); to the wp-config.php file and I'm still getting the same issue. Did I do it right?

Comment: Honestly, I am really not sure, I am not much of a wordpress expert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by deleting the .htaccess in the /var/www/example directory and removing the  lines in the conf file.